# 2 Sites both hosted with Digital Ocean on UCEPROTECTL3 blacklist - why? And what are the downsides of this?

Tags: ip-address, blacklist

I've got hosting for various sites with various providers.

Two of my sites are hosted on separate Digital Ocean servers, both of which are located in the London data centre, and both of which have IPs that start 46.101. (although the C and D blocks are both different).

When I ran DNS and black list check recently both of these sites are showing up as being on the UCEPROTECTL3 black list.

Any idea why this could be and if it can negatively effect: SEO, Email deliverability or anything else? How can I get the blacklisting removed?

Comment: Check the domain name and IP addresses here: https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx This site will tell you exactly why and what to do to remove the listing. Just follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough i actually first found the issue when doing a bulk DNS check earlier today using mxtoolbox.com

Comment: It is a good site and the only I use because of that fact. Sometimes, you will find that some blacklists will trigger against a whole IP address block because of one bad actor. That happened to me. However, you can easily lift these. That should not happen these days, but some blacklist operators are nuts. I was a web host before retiring and found that some blacklists are seriously ill conceived and harmful. Some still are. It is not uncommon that when a blacklist is shutdown, they return positive hits on everyone to bring attention to the fact they shutdown. Crazy. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, i read a bit more on the UCEPROTECTL3 (level 3) list and it seems its due to more than 0.2% of sites spamming malware-ing etc. Because of this they put all IP on the list it seems. In my eyes this is pretty unfair for a self serve cloud hosting platform like Digital Ocean (others would be Linode, AWS, Google Cloud, Azure etc)